# Bind label text value to String property of external file

Tags: java, javafx, properties, kotlin, tornadofx

I have an external text file that I want to bind to a label so that when the external file value is modified, my UI auto-updates the string value.

So far, I have tried:

```
val testid: ObservableStringValue = SimpleStringProperty(File("src/.../test").readText())
```

And in my borderpane, I reference the testid

```
label.bind(testid)
```

This reads the file successfully, but the testid doesn't auto update its value when I edit the test file. I thought to try using a Handler() to force the variable to update the value every second, but I'm sure there's a smarter way to use Properties and .observable() to bind the file and Property together.

EDIT:

Following on from mipa's suggestion to use nio2, I'm having trouble producing the object/class for the timer:

```
object DirectoryWatcher {

    @JvmStatic  fun main(args:Array<String>) {
    val watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()
    val path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("src/pykotinterface/test"))

    path.register(
    watchService,
    StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE,
    StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE,
    StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY)

    val key:WatchKey = watchService.take()
    while (key != null) {
    for (event in key.pollEvents()) {
    println(
            "Event kind:" + event.kind()
            + ". File affected: " + event.context() + ".")
            }
    key.reset()
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I call this object to run - it's currently resting inside my View() class which is being called by TornadoFX to produce the view, so I can't call DirectWatcher.main(). Do I place a call to this object from within the other App class? I'm very lost.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in mechanism in JavaFX which would allow such a binding but you can use the Java watch service as described here:
http://www.baeldung.com/java-nio2-watchservice
The Oracle doc can be found here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html

Comment: ty for the answer, please see the edit provided. I've made a watchservice object but I'm having trouble figuring out how to call it from within the view class to run within my UI. Where does it belong? My intention is to have its return affect a label within the view.